# Not able to add field for related list in page layout

Tags: related-list

I am not able to add field named '**Related to**' for **open activities** related list in opportunity page layout

Is it possible to set in page layout of **OPEN ACTIVITIES** & **ACTIVITY HISTORY** ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: To clarify you question, are you asking if you can add the Related To field from Task to the related lists of activities on an Opportunity?  If so, there's no need.  The Related To field simply limits the WhatID field of activities to appropriate object.  By the nature of the functionality, if the activity is displayed in the Opportunity related list, it is related to opportunities.

Comment: I just need to display Related To field in opportunity's related list named OPEN ACTIVITIES.

Comment: My point above is that even if you could (which you cannot, since that value is not stored as a field or data) it would display "Opportunity" in the related list of an Opportunity.  It is redundnant.

Comment: absolutely I am agree with you that it is redundant but is it possible to display ?

Comment: I got your point what you trying to say (it is related to opportunity that is why it is redundant)....So, Why we need to add that field under the Opportunity page layout.....Right ?

Comment: The actual stored value is the ID of the related opportunity.  You can add "Related To" to the related list, but it will simply display the name of the related record.  If you want "Opportunity" to display, then you'll need to create a formula that evaluates the ID of the lookup into a text string.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display Related to field in the related list of opportunity page layout. Because, related to field is basically the opportunity lookup to which the task/event is linked. And in the related list, only those tasks/events are displayed which are linked( related to) to the opportunity. So, there is no need of the related to field.
Let me know if this helps.